# Undefined reference to symbol 'glFrontFace'

Tags: c++, opengl-3

I have spent all day trying to resolve this issue and now am looking for a bit of help.

My global Linker settings: 
-lGL -lGLU -lpthread -lXrandr -lXxf86vm -lXi -lXinerama -lX11 -l/usr/lib/libglfw.sso

I have two projects, one is a library used by the other.

When I compile Project A, it compiles into a library without issue.  When i compile Project B, while also linking to the library created by Project A, I get the error in the title.

the compiler command is(called from Project B)(libEngine.a is the result of Project A):
g++ -L/usr/lib -o bin/Debug/Game obj/Debug/main.o obj/Debug/src/MyScene.o  -lGL -lGLU -lpthread -lXrandr -lXxf86vm -lXi -lXinerama -lX11  ../Engine/bin/Debug/libEngine.a /usr/lib/libglfw.so

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is libGL.so file or link present in `/usr/lib`? If yes. then check the pressence/architecture of the (lib) file pointed by the link. Use `-lglut` if applicable.

Comment: that did it, there was a link missing in /usr/lib, the actual GL library was in /usr/lib/nvidia-331

Comment: I will add this as answer then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is `libGL.so` file or link present in `/usr/lib`? If yes. then check the pressence/architecture of the (lib) file pointed by the link. I hope this will solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This was aswered by Gyapti jain, there was a missing link to the actual location of the library.  the missing link belonged in /usr/lib, the library was in /usr/library/nvidia-331